# Unmerge word cells VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

i need unmerge word cells to get the number of merged rows [Like this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBGt5.png), but 
I can't find a function in a VSTO object model. Any ideas for this trouble?

Comment: If you just need the information you can probably get it more efficiently by reading and parsing the Table.Range.WordOpenXML markup. Table definitions are very similar to HTML and can give you the "spans" without needing to change the original table structures. But if you want to use the approach you're considering, record a macro in Word while unmerging cells and that will give you the basic syntax.

Comment: Thks Cindy Meister, it works with openxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the information you can probably get it more efficiently by reading and parsing the Table.Range.WordOpenXML markup. Table definitions are very similar to HTML and can give you the "spans" without needing to change the original table structures. But if you want to use the approach you're considering, record a macro in Word while unmerging cells and that will give you the basic syntax.